# Exception in thread when i using thread pool executer

Tags: java, exception

I get the following type of error and I want to know why this type of error appears:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-24077" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at etc.popserver.Pop3Handler.run(Pop3Handler.java:332)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: The program tries to dereference an uninitialized pointer. Could you please show the source code that leads to this error?

Comment: what is etc.popserver.Pop3Handler? can you give the code?